# Method in C++ to call a function every certain number of minutes

Tags: c++, timer, function-call

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and C++, I need to call a function every 5 minutes, I've managed to do it but it consumes 25% of my CPU which is far from ideal.

The code is as follows,

```
time_t start;
time_t end;
time(&start);
while (1) {
time(&end);
double dif = difftime (end,start);
if (dif >= 300) { autofunction(); time(&start);} else {} }
```

Is there a more CPU efficient way to go about calling a function every 5 minutes or any way to slow down my while loop?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can just use `Sleep` function.

Comment: I should of probably mentioned that I don't want to use sleep because I want to do other things at the same time.

Comment: @user1661022 in the else part of your if statement you do those other things?

Comment: "25% cpu" doesn't mean all that much these days. You probably mean, it uses 100% of 1 of my 4 cpu's, or "it takes all cpu time it gets", or something like that

Comment: How about setting a timer via `SetTimer()` and then handling the WM_TIMER message?

Comment: What kind of application is it? You can create second thread and let it sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has Sleep(), and for something that happens every 300 seconds, that's perfectly good. There are also timers in Windows, which potentially takes a timerproc argument, which is a function - but note that this is a C function, not C++, so it mustn't be a class member function unless it is a static one.

Comment: Umm, I think it's perfectly fine to pass a lambda or `std::bind` there.

Comment: Yes, as long as it's not a member function, anything that is "directly callable as a function" should work just fine. I didn't want to write an essay on ALL of the restrictions and tricks with callback functions, but at least mention that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody suggested that, you can just spawn a new `std::thread` and `Sleep` in it.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). You constantly check for the time being elapsed and so use up the CPU time.

Since you're on windows, [Using Timer Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be of interest.

This creates a timer with a callback function. You can do other work, while waiting for the timer to expire.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer will depend on some more of the details of what you're doing.  If you only need it to be approximately 5 minutes, maybe you can put the duration-elapsed calculation at a more programmatically convenient location, and you'll run the task the first time after 5 minutes when you check.

Otherwise, it seems like @BartekBanachewicz has the best suggestion of starting a thread, which uses `sleep`---without blocking your main thread doing whatever you're doing.  As long as your main thread will definitely be running longer than 5 minutes, it shouldn't be a problem to always re-`join()` the thread at the end, or whenever.

Using thread's has the benefit of not requiring any windows specific stuff -- e.g. @OlafDietsche's suggestion, whatever Timer Queues are.  With c++0x, threads are super-easy to use, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread; http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html